# Problema de estilos al cargar una pagina en wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

> **EDIT: El error solo aparece en mozilla firefox. En chrome y safari se ve todo correctamente**

Tengo un problema con poco código así que voy a tratar de dejar imágenes de lo que sucede. Espero sepan disculpar.

**Imagino que podría solucionar este problema con alguna función de javascript, pero realmente no entiendo a qué se debe. Si algún experto en wordpress puede darme alguna recomendación, estaría mas que agradecido**

Estoy haciendo una tienda online con WP y WooCommerce, y tengo un problema al cargar la página.

Dejo algunas capturas de lo que sucede:

- Si yo ingreso a la página, o si le doy `actualizar` estando en la parte de arriba de la página (Sin scrollear digamos), se carga. Y una vez que scrolleo para abajo, se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Si yo estoy visualizando este error, y vuelvo al top de la página y vuelvo a actualizarla, sigue el error. En cambio si yo actualizo en la posicion donde se visualiza el error, el sitio se carga correctamente, que es de esta manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Para el sitio estoy usando el theme de `Flatsome`. Los pluguins que tengo instalados son los siguientes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Por último, este es el CSS personalizado que fui agregando. El ultimo selector es el que corresponde al footer. Al aplicar esas propiedades veo como se acomoda correctamente desde el personalizador de WP, pero cuando ingreso al sitio se me presenta lo mostrado anteriormente.

```
    #content.page-wrapper{
      padding-top:0px !important;
      margin-top:-35px
    }

    .sub-menu.nav-dropdown.nav-dropdown-default.dropdown-uppercase{
      max-height: 70vh !important;
      display: flex;
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }

    .woocommerce-message.message-wrapper{
      display:none;
    }

    .absolute-footer{
      bottom: 0 !important;
      position: absolute !important;
      width: 100% !important; 
    }
```

Comment: Flatsome es de paga, lo que debes hacer es contactar a su desarrollador y hacer valida la garantía para que te dé el soporte necesario, por algo pagaste la licencia.

Comment: Si, ya lo hice. Tambien me hice un usuario en este sitio por algo jaja. Gracias de todas maneras.